# Install VMware Player image as a dual boot OS?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot, vmware-player

Ok so I have Ubuntu installed on VMWare in my Win 8 PC. Now, I want to dualboot it with Ubuntu but with the exact same configs, apps and data as on my VM. How do I do that?

Is there any way I could dual boot off of my VM?

Comment: why are you using vmware on win8? why not hyper-v? And if you want dual boot why not create a second parition instead of vmware or hyper-v? am I following you correctly? or do you want to dual boot inside your vm?

Comment: I don't find these questions relevant to what I asked. But still: because I'm used to it. I like it. It's free and simple. I started using Ubuntu as a VM but now I find that I use it more than my windows. So I want to "port" the VM as a dual-boot.

Comment: you dont find my questions relevent? If it was a hyper-v image it would be dead simple to "port" it to a dual boot (via Attach VHD). Instead its like mixing apples and oranges... now you need to convert the vmware vm to a compatible hyper-v vm.

Comment: Well, I don't have a hyper-v image. So yeah, how do I install a VMware Player image as a dual boot OS?